# How does melting of Antarctica's ice cause rise in sea level?

Tags: fluid-statics

It is clear from Archimedes Principle that, floating ice when melts completely *does not cause any rise in water level*
, then how sea level is rising?

Comment: Antarctica is land covered in ice. It is not floating.

Comment: And @Steeven. Relatively surprising, or surprising to at least us, most of Arctic ice is land ice, too. https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-is-worldwide-sea-level-rise-driven-by-melting-arctic-ice/

Comment: @Alchimista The Arctic might include the inland ice on Greenland, which constitutes *a lot* of the land-based ice of the world.

Comment: Yes is that. Then it is just surprising to me and probably the OP. Either you knew it or guessed have a look at the link. It is quite interesting.

Comment: But Glaciers are also melting read:https://grist.org/article/antarctica-doomsday-glaciers-could-flood-coastal-cities/

Answer (score 3):

Rising temperatures melt sea ice, which would have no effect on sea level if the ice had the same salinity as the sea water, and we won't concern ourselves with the small effect that comes from taking a salinity difference into account. Of more concern is the fact that land ice, be it Antarctic or otherwise, slips into the sea and thereby increases the water supply.

A warmer world experiences sea level rises for another notable reason: a kilogram of liquid water expands when heated (not by as much as metal, but since the ocean is kilometres deep it matters). Admittedly water is at its densest slightly above its melting point, which complicates the analysis somewhat.